# C++ - Error C4430: missing type specifier (for a constructor???)

Tags: c++

I've been stuck with this since last night, and for the life of me, I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening. I must be missing something very simple.

I'm making an OpenGL program. In this program, I'm making a DialogBox class. Below is the code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------
//DialogBox.h
//---------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vector>

class DialogBox
{
    private:

      float X; float Y; float Z;
      float Width;
      float Height;

      float RED;
      float GREEN;
      float BLUE;
      float ALPHA;

      int currentLine; 
      int maxLines;    //How many lines of text this dialog box can hold
      int maxChars;    //How many chars each line of text can hold

      std::vector< std::vector<char> >Text; //Text contents of the Dialog Box

      unsigned int vertexArray_DialogBox;
      unsigned int vertexBuffer_DialogBox;


   public:

      DialogBox();
      DialogBox(float width, float height);

      void draw();
      void draw(float x, float y, float z);

};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//DialogBox.cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <iostream>
#include "DialogBox.h"

DialogBox::DialogBox()
{
    X = 0.0f; Y = 0.0f; Z = 0.0f;

    Width = 1.0f;
    Height = 1.0f;

    RED = 0.0f;
    GREEN = 1.0f;
    BLUE = 1.0f;
    ALPHA = 1.0f;

    //For HELVETICA_18 ----------------------
    static const float letter_width = 0.03f;
    static const float letter_height = 0.04f;
    static const float line_height = 0.1f;
    //---------------------------------------


   maxLines = Height / line_height - 4; 
   maxChars = Width / letter_width - 2; 

   Text.resize(maxLines);
   for(int i = 0; i < maxLines; i++)
   {
       Text[i].resize(maxChars);
   }
}

DialogBox::DialogBox(float width, float height)
{
    Width = width;
    Height = height;
    //The rest of the initialization codes
}

void DialogBox::draw()
{
    //OpenGL Drawing codes
}

void DialogBox::draw(float x, float y, float z)
{
    X = x; Y = y; Z = z;
    draw();
}
```

And the compiler threw this error message:

[image]

I have been pulling my hairs out, but I couldn't figure out what the compiler were referring to. It must be something really simple (like a typo in the codes or something like that). Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try renaming your class to a less likely name than DialogBox. Microsoft already provides something with that name. As an alternative, see if not including <iostream> or any system header helps.

Comment: BINGO! Would you please post this as an Answer so I can accept it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft already provides a function (macro?) with the name DialogBox:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It probably got pulled in by `<iostream>`, `<vector>` or whatever. Renaming your class to a more original name should help.

Comment: I couldn't believe that I didn't think about something like this last night. It's so helpful to have a 2nd set of eyes looking at your codes sometimes. Thank you again!

Answer (score 7):

What's that warning on the same line?

> not enough actual parameters for macro 'DialogBoxA'

Is `DialogBox` a `#define`-d macro?  If so, that would probably mess things up.

Comment: This looks like a winner to me. Although I wonder how it became `#define`d when there's no trace of that in OP's code.

Comment: No, I did not define DialogBox as a macro. I define it just like a normal C++ class. I don't know why it's showing that "macro" warning on the same line. The codes I showed you are everything I created regarding the DialogBox class.

Comment: Are you including Windows.h at all?  That has a [DialogBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro in it.

Comment: Yeah, I included windows.h in the main.cpp file. That was probably the culprit of the problem. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you, aschepler, for hinting out the root of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When I compile your code, I get an error on `DialogBox::draw()`, because you're not specifying the return type there. Specifically, this is on the implementation, not the declaration. That's the only compiler error I find in your code. Perhaps your compiler is just flagging the wrong line?

Comment: Oh, I missed the "void" before the draw() function when I copied my codes over. Sorry about that. I have edited and updated my codes on the first post.